# When running Word 2007 in ASP - Is it server-side or client-side?

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, client-side, server-side

I managed to run Microsoft Office Word 2007 and programmatically manipulate doc files in ASP using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` .Net Component. I used the tutorial found at [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/f8989c05-d04a-4b4a-be0f-fc0055691de7) The question is: Was the Word application run on the server side or on the client? I was only able to test this on my own computer in debug mode so it's kind of both the server and the client and I couldn't figure out which one it is.

And the other question is: If it's running on the server is there any way to use the client's Word application? I mean instead of needing a Word installed on the server could we make use of the Word installed on the client's computer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's running on the server just like all of your C#/VB.NET code.  Since the web browser tries its best to isolate websites from the host computer, you can't easily access "their" Office.  I'm sure if it was absolutely necessary, you could write an ActiveX that could be installed that performed the hand off.  But why do you need it to do so?

Comment: Thanks. Well I am not sure about the legal issues. Could I just use a normal home edition office and install it on the server? And the other thing is: my company's Web application is supposed to manipulate many doc files and turn them to PDF with 'SaveAsPDFandXPS' and I thought maybe that would consume loads of bandwidth.

Comment: That's an interesting question that I'm not qualified to answer.  Several years ago the company I worked for did something similar.  But I think it was the professional version (or whatever they call it).  As long as it's on 1 machine (as per your license key agreement) and you have permission to use it for commercial purposes (and with Office, you do), then I don't think it's a problem.